# why my dxf file not working in AutoCAD giving me ID 11 incorrect: already used

Tags: autocad, dxf

I have generated a dxf file but when I opened it with AutoCAD, crashes AutoCAD and gives a message ID 11 incorrect: already used.
the dxf content: https://github.com/tarikjabiri/dxf/blob/dev/examples/latest.dxf
I can't spot the problem 3 days I am trying to solve it.
I think something wrong with the APPID because it holding the ID 11 or the Handle in the language of DXF.

I have a dxf working: https://github.com/tarikjabiri/dxf/blob/dev/examples/Minimal_DXF_AC1021.dxf

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two minor issues:

1. `DIMSTYLE` table

```
  0
TABLE
  2
DIMSTYLE
105    <<< handle group code of the table "head" is 5 as usual
8
  100
AcDbSymbolTable
  100
AcDbDimStyleTable
  70
1
  0
DIMSTYLE
  5    <<< handle group code of the table entry is 105
12
  330
8
  100
AcDbSymbolTableRecord
  100
AcDbDimStyleTableRecord
  2
STANDARD
  70
0
  40
1
```

2. `BLOCK_RECORD` table entries for `*MODEL_SPACE` and `*PAPER_SPACE`

```
  0
TABLE
  2
BLOCK_RECORD
  5
9
  330
0
  100
AcDbSymbolTable
  70
2
  0
BLOCK_RECORD
  5
14
  330
9
  100
AcDbSymbolTableRecord
  100
AcDbRegAppTableRecord    <<< subclass marker string "AcDbBlockTableRecord"
  2
*MODEL_SPACE
  70
0
  70
0
  280
```

After this changes the file opens in Autodesk DWG Trueview 2022.